# HTML Input not draggable in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, draggable, html-input

First see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/byVRijG29joCRI6nN08P?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div style="height:100px;width:100px; background-color:blue" draggable="true"></div>
    <input disabled draggable="true"/>
    <script>

    </script>
  </body>


</html>
```

In Chrome, both the blue square and the text input are draggable.
But in Safari, only the blue square is draggable. The input field does not work.

Is there a work around for Safari? I have tried wrapping the input with dives and making the div draggable and still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[See this Forked Plunker for the functioning work around described below:](https://plnkr.co/edit/HT5Agyk4kicA1odsMLiT?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      const selectInput = () => {
        let target = document.getElementById('input');
        target.className = "";
        target.focus();
      };

      const disableInput = () => {
        document.getElementById('input').className = "input-disabled";
      };
    </script>
    <style>
      .input-disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div style="height:100px;width:100px; background-color:blue" draggable="true"></div>

    <div draggable="true" onmouseup="selectInput();">
      <input id="input" class='input-disabled' onblur="disableInput();" />
    </div>

  </body>      

</html>
```

The steps are:

1. Wrap the input in a draggable div
2. Disable mouse events on the input via the "pointer-events: none;" CSS property
3. Add an onmouseup callback to the div that selects the input, removes the "pointer-events: none;" CSS property, and assigns the input focus
4. Add an onblur callback to the input that re-adds the "pointer-events: none;" CSS property such that the div will be draggable again once the user leaves the input field